# Dropzone HEIC images uploaded as JPG do not save

Tags: jpeg, dropzone, heic

I'm using Dropzone for image uploads.  If a HEIC image is uploaded I use heic2any to convert the file using this bit of code: https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/issues/1984#issuecomment-886460171. I check the `file.type` and if it is an `image/heic` I do the conversion. It works great for a HEIC image on my laptop namely the uploaded image is recognized as a HEIC image and is successfully converted and saved.

The issue is uploading a HEIC image from the iPhone.  When the image is received, it is a `image/jpeg` and therefore I don't convert it with heic2any.  It seems if the uploaded HEIC image is small, it gets converted to a JPEG successfully without heic2any.  However, larger HEIC images that are received as a JPG aren't successfully saved.  If the larger HEIC image is uploaded from the laptop it does work since it's recognized as a `image/heic` and hits the heic2any code.

Any suggestions for how to handle larger HEIC images uploaded from a iPhone that are somehow converted and received as a JPEG having not gone through heic2any but are not saving?